# Slice input vue js

Tags: vue.js, split

I just started programming in vue. js.
I want to program a clock that outputs as text a time after typing it in hh:mm format.

To do this, I have to divide the input into minutes and hours and save the values in a variable. How do you do that? Can I use split?

Answer (score 0):

You may use [VueJS Computed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#computed) & Javascript [Split function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) to achieve what you need.

Eg:

```
data: () => ({
  userInput: ''  // 08:33
}),
computed: {
  hours: function() {
    return this.userInput.split(":")[0]  // return 08
  },
  minutes: function() {
    return this.userInput.split(":")[1]  // return 33
  }
}
```

Computed method will listen to the change of `userInput` in this case. Meaning if the user key in 08:33, then decided to change to 08:44, the `minutes` will react and change to 44.